# Fabric js - start free drawing if mouse in DIV

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

There was a task to do a function with the Fabric Js library (free drawing).
Is it possible to make it so that when changing the Boolean variable `canvas.isDrawingMode = false // true` - if `true`, then draw always, regardless of whether the left mouse button is held down, if `false` - do not draw?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('sheet');
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 2;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "#ff0000";
canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);

$(window).mouseup(function() {
  canvas.clear();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    #sheet {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="sheet"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to call fabric's internal `_onMouseDownInDrawingMode()`/`_onMouseUpInDrawingMode()` on `mouse:over`/`mouse:out` events. However, since `mouse:over` event is not called when mouse enters over an existing fabric.js object (e.g. a part of a path), we'll need to tinker with the `fabric.Canvas.prototype._onMouseEnter()` a little bit.

Here's a complete solution:

```js
fabric.Canvas.prototype._onMouseEnter = (function (original) {
  return function (e) {
    if (this.isDrawingMode) {
      // reset cached pointer, otherwise new path will be started from the point cursor last left the canvas
      this._resetTransformEventData();
      this._onMouseDownInDrawingMode(e);
    }
  }
  return original.apply(this, arguments)
})(fabric.Canvas.prototype._onMouseEnter)

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('sheet');

canvas.on('mouse:out', function (e) {
  if (this.isDrawingMode) {
    this._onMouseUpInDrawingMode(e)
  }
});

canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 2;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "#ff0000";
canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    #sheet {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas width="100" height="100" id="sheet"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```